# My images are not displayed using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imagesource

I have a small problem, I am trying to display a list of items, but it is not working, each item contains an image, so here is my Activity :

```
public class TestRecyclerImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.listImages)
    RecyclerView listImages;


    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.images_list);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        ImageModel img = new ImageModel("test1");
        List list = new ArrayList<ImageModel>();

        list.add(img);
        list.add(img);

        list.add(img);
        list.add(img);


        adapter = new ImageListAdapter(this, list);

        this.listImages.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.listImages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
}
```

And here is my Adapter :

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

    List<ImageModel> images;
    Context context;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, List<ImageModel> contracts){
        this.context = context;
        this.images = contracts;

    }

    public void updateImages(List<ImageModel> newImages){
        images.clear();
        images.addAll(newImages);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false); // ContratBinding >> as your list item layout named "contrat"
        return new ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.images.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.img)
        ImageView image;

        public ImageViewHolder(View iview){
            super(iview);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, iview);
        }

        void bind(ImageModel imageModel){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
        }

    }


}
```

This my listImages layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/newimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So why it is not displaying anything? I feel like I did everything right.

For the Image src, it is not dynamic now, I am using directly an image in my drawable, I set the source with code, did not work, set it in the XML, did not work, set it in both and lol did not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the imageview you have wrap content try it in match_constrain, and you need on onCreateViewHolder to return your view and say that in the view like

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false);
ImageView object = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img);
```

you have the image view now, now pick the image source and pass it to the source of the object.

Comment: I am using ButterKnife annotation to get my element

Comment: never worked with butterknife annotation but in there code they say the you need to return the view at the same

Comment: public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  @Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view != null) {
      holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    } else {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder(view);
      view.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.name.setText("John Doe");
    // etc...

    return view;
  }

Comment: I am returning new ImageViewHolder already, I think you just did not see

Comment: The image model recieves a uri and you are sending a simple string, maybe that it was wrong try to make a log about it and send me so I can check.

Comment: the ImageModel is there as a parameter, but not using it yet. my image is an imageView image.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);

Comment: I will try to say that you have the RecyclerView in wrap content and wrap content the list inside have a refresh but the recycler dosent have when the view is create is still in wrap from the bigining that is 0 x 0 so make match constrain hope this works

Answer (score 1):

**First Thing**
Try setting layoutmanager before adapter

```
this.listImages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); 
this.listImages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Second thing**

Make recyclerview width match_parent and its parent LinearLayout's width also match_parent

**Third thing**

Provide required orientation to your layout manager like vertical/horizontal

**Fourth thing**

Initialize ur arraylist in the adapter itself, and on update clear and addAll new list

public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
List<ImageModel> images = new ArrayList();
Context context;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, List<ImageModel> contracts){
    this.context = context;
    this.images.clear();
    this.addAll(contracts);
}
```

**Fifth Thing**

Try giving fixed height to the imageview, Currently it is wrap_content

Comment: Make recyclerview width match_parent and its parent LinearLayout's width also match_parent

Comment: Ummm, No did not work, I don't think it is a styling problem

Comment: @TaouBen hahaha.. I surrender!!

Comment: No problem, I surrendered too Haha, it is weird since I feel like I did everything right

Comment: Lol! Just last pointer too, You can check view using "Show layout Bound" option that is in Settings in "Developer Option". When you will enable it, You will be able to see outlines of all the views, Maybe it can give you some clue in the issue.

Comment: can you point where is that exactly, I am new to this envirment

Comment: So basically there is a setting "Developer Option" in Android Device, Which is hidden by default, If You have not opened it yet, and there are some shortcuts to make it visible, mostlikely it will be to go to -> Settings-> About Phone-> Phone Build No -> Click multiple times on it-> Developer option will be opened -> In Developer Setting there will be many developer related settings, one of them would be "Show Layout Bounds". This whole process may differ on phone device manufaturer etc, You can google it based on Your device manufaturer.